# SO Reputation list day-by-day seems incorrect compared to total. Why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes

If I view my SO reputation for 10/1/2009 - 10/1/2009, I see the 5 questions listed, with no down-voting (second red column is all zeros) and a combined first column of 125.

If I view my reputation for 9/30/2009 - 9/30/2009, I see the 8 questions listed, with no down-voting (second red column is all zeros) and a combined first column of 160.

(2 of the questions are common between 9/30 and 10/01 lists)

If I view my reputation for 9/30/2009 - 10/1/2009, I see the 17!!! questions listed

- 7 of them have "-2" down-votes (and I saw my rep drop by ~10 points within 1/2 hour today, so it did happen recenlt)
- A combined first column of 285.

Question 1: How come the 7 down-votes on 7 questions do not show up in either 9/30 nor 10/1 view?

Question 2: How can I tell whether some of the 7 down-votes were a result of serial downvoter (I know 100% sure that at least 3 of them were voted down within 1 minute as I saw it on my Recent screen).

Thanks!

Comment: Allow me to provide you with a tip that will help you in the future: questioning the reputation system only leads to madness.

Comment: Your third date range should be 09/30/09 - 10/01/09

Comment: @John - thanks!!! Duh. Fixed.

Comment: @Pesto - Ain't I already mad to be answering questions on SO?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Something wrong with finding a bug in software system?

Comment: Maybe people don't like you?  (Just somethin' I've heard recently...)

Comment: +1 from me, but the downvotes I'm guessing are because people are tired of seeing the constant reputation bugs brought to meta with what appears to be no chance of them being fixed - which is why I'm with Pesto on this one... just ignore it and let the system take care of revenge downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these inconsistencies are now taken care of as part of [the new reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).  Totals and votes should no longer be out of sync.  This is currently active here on meta and rolling out to the rest of the network soon.