# Recent Reputation History Changes

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-recalc

**Update (March, 2012):** This has been rolled out to all sites in the network except Area 51.

---

Behind the scenes we've been hard at work making some changes to how we track reputation.  Here are some of the issues we're aiming to address with these changes:

- Reputation Skew (your *actual* reputation doesn't match what's shown)
- Up/Down votes oddities (mostly with the daily rep cap, the magical +2)
- Historical Deletes (not impacting rep immediately, contributing to skew)
- Unaccepts (display issues in the profile)
- User Deletion (magically missing rep, another skew contributor)

To be clear: **reputation values are not changing, every action in the system is still worth the same amount**.   Here’s what *will* be different:

- Your reputation will be correct at all times
- Deletions will have a much more immediate effect on reputation, not waiting on a recalc  (but reputation sync takes up to 5 minutes on a delete/undelete action; as to not block the user's response thread, it's offloaded to a background queue)
- Recalcs will no longer be necessary
- Up/Down vote reversals will restore the correct reputation amount
- Up/Down vote reversals will correctly adjust to the reputation cap
- The reputation history in your profile will be more detailed and accurate (e.g. when a post is deleted, you'll see that in the reputation tab of your profile)

This means your reputation will go up and down more than it has previously, but it will be in sync.  To think of it more easily: imagine that a recalc will be done after every action in the system.

Probably the biggest impact many will be concerned with is that you may see your reputation drop in cases where it didn't *seem* like it did before  This was effectively happening before, but the results of that change were not applied immediately, but on the next rep recalc.  Post deletion is the biggest factor here, previously it didn't (immediately) account for the reputation impact...that will no longer be the case.  Reputation changes from the deletion will now be applied within the hour, and most other changes will be instant.

Now the part that will make everyone throw vegetables our way:  this will require a global recalc to get everything in sync.  We'll be rolling it out first here on meta, then the rest of the network...the enabling of the detailed rep view and global recalc on each individual site will coincide.  During the rollout you will see empty reputation tabs on profiles as we transition to the new storage behind the scenes, they'll be restored as the recalc rolls though each user.  We’ll put up a blog post on https://stackoverflow.blog/ before the network-wide rollout.

If you have any questions about this change or details I may have left out, please do so in answers below so that we can clear up as much as possible before this rolls out.

Comment: Here's a feature request waiting for a (now) easy answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115201/change-the-reputation-recalc-error-message-to-once-every-24-hours

Comment: My Rep! My ill-gotten rep! NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: Now I'm going to have to spend all night bidding a tearful goodbye to each of those 538 points that you're senselessly slaughtering. You monster.

Comment: Will we still have access to the reputation audit page, just without the recalc button?

Comment: @animuson - we don't plan to remove it, but it may get an update to provide a bit more data...right now that mechanism still wouldn't show post deletion for example (no plans to update it *at this time* though).

Comment: Just be aware that this will quite increase the number of people that will complain about drops in their reputation and that will come to meta to fight over the deletion of some question/answer.

Comment: I guess experience tells you that people really do freak out about this. It sounds like a great plan to me, and gets around the fact that we were limited to only one rep recalc per day. There's really no good reason for the data to be out of sync. Related: [Minimise reputation flux due to deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43426/minimise-reputation-flux-due-to-deleted-posts), [Make reputation recalcs unnecessary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43979/make-reputation-recalcs-unnecessary)

Comment: Will wrong vote counts also be fixed? **<[Bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122263/after-a-forced-vote-recalc-the-old-counts-are-still-used)>**

Comment: @RobW - they already are every night, see my answer to that question.

Comment: Will the blog be publishing the order of site roll-out? Or will it be a surprise?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - the rollout will be very quick across all sites, the order shouldn't matter much really, it's just a processing time thing since recalcs are quite expensive.

Comment: So. It has come to this.

Comment: @DavRob60 [very dramatic](http://www.xkcd.com/1022)

Comment: WAAAAAAT!1! NOOO00OO I just got my 10k rep. :D

Comment: Good. I feel dirty when I have "unearned" rep after I have deleted upvoted content. The next recalc window can never happen soon enough.

Comment: Cool! Will it affect the global flair as well and make it always sync with the real reputation?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - yes and no, flair is still cached for a few days, but it will have a correct number every time it's refreshed.

Comment: @Kev: Hehe. Back on 9.8 :D

Comment: @NickCraver: Nick, I'm just curious: How do you store this history? Is it everything in `votes` table? Is it/will it be visible/reproduceable from a dump?

Comment: As Meta now overshadows SO on my global flair, I've been working diligently to shed as much rep here as possible. Gonna have to work harder, as I'll be losing about 200 on SO soon. Or I could go .. ya know .. answer a few questions or something.

Comment: @mmyers after extensive research and expense, we have invested in a robust reputation storage and nurturing facilty (adjacent to the colo). All reputation points not needed at the current time will be humanely relocated there and allowed to relax and mingle. When new reputation is required, we will use the reputation from this facility until exhausted. No reputation points will be slaughtered - not even harmed a little - in this exercise. "The Reputation Defence League" and the "Humane Treatment for Points Society" can call off their blockades.

Comment: I just noticed that I've 1000 more votes than the last time I checked my total vote count. Particularly the downvotes have almost doubled. That seems to be votes on deleted posts. Is this related to this new reputation history change? I can't find any notice about that in this announcement.

Comment: @Chichiray - Unrelated but recent change, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048

Comment: Thank you much, Nick. That clarified everything.

Comment: Vegetables coming your way mighty quick. :-)

Comment: Once all seems good, when are you planning to move it to the main site?

Comment: @minitech - starting around 12-1PM EST today we'll be rolling this out everywhere

Comment: +1 for the banner message

Comment: *Reputation changed unexpectedly? Don't know where to turn? We've moved heaven and earth to ensure your score is always correct!* I feel the earth move under my feet I feel the sky come tumbling, tumbling down!

Comment: my reputation just dropped 1000 points today. I don't think I had 1000 points of answers deleted today.

Comment: @Mike - they weren't deleted *today* they were deleted any time between the last recalc and today (you haven't been recalced in 11 months)...going forward it'll be within 5 minutes, rather than indefinitely off until a recalc.

Comment: Whoa...that's pretty brutal. I was excited because I wasn't far off from 10k. Oh well...time to answer more questions (or I guess work on my book :P)

Comment: Why throw away all those perfectly good reputation points? They still need a home. I officially offer my profile as a storage facility for all rejected reputation points. I will give them a good home and make sure they are well cared for! :P

Comment: *Alms, uh, I mean rep for the poor? Rep for the poor?*

Comment: I feel sorry for all digital sharecroppers.

Comment: So how long will that notice banner be up on SO? Why couldn't you make it like the other notifications where we can close them?

Comment: I have been robbed!! Don't you think it is just wrong to delete a question that other people have spent their time answering them?

Comment: What it does is, where there's a rep transaction, and the points are computed in the thousands a day in fractions of a point, which it usually rounds off. What this does is it takes those remainders and puts it into your account... Just like in Superman III.

Comment: Oh wow, all these horror stories made me scared I was going to lose hundreds or thousands of rep points when the calculation hit stackoverflow.com, but I was pleasantly surprised to find I *gained* 6 points. I must have downvoted a lot of answers on posts that eventually got deleted, enough to more than make up for any upvotes I got on posts that got deleted.

Comment: mine went up on meta but down on so, not sure if I should be happy or sad

Comment: My reputation... :(

Comment: @j08691, second that! These persistently shown one-time notices are extremely annoying.

Comment: Good thing you didn't touch the badges.

Comment: Also please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64118/allow-us-an-exit-hatch-to-dismiss-the-system-message-notification-bar !

Comment: **"questions... in answers below"** Nick could you think of a way to make that statement more prominent? Bold font or maybe move it on top or both? **I just submitted a fake not-an-answer flag because I did not notice that part at first sight. And cast an erroneous downvote (which I was luckily able to revoke)**

Comment: I don't really understand. I have lost over 80 rep points on my Stack account and there is nothing new in the reputation history to show the drop. I don't understand what has been so out of sync for weeks, that suddenly I could lose that amount.

Comment: Blatant advertisement of the [CSS method to block this message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124195/180044) :-)

Comment: Woohoo!  I got 2 points closer to catching The Skeet :-)

Comment: The arithmetic is fine. The reputation comment "Voting fraud reversed" is extremely offensive and need fixing. See here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/whats-going-on-with-reputation

Comment: @Brent.Longborough - someone did that *to you*, not you being fradulent...it's certainly not meant to be offensive, I'm open to better copy on this, absolutely...it's an arbitrary string at the moment.  I'll migrate your question here and see if anyone has better suggestions.

Comment: In my SO profile it was the slaughter of the clone points: their immigrant originals in SF and SU can now rest in the piece of being unique once again. Except... the points of an immigrated post are the *original* ones, right? You did kill *the copies*, right?

Comment: @thkala - honestly they all looked like cyborgs... The points on the destination site aren't "the originals" per se, but they are votes created as copies of the original votes from the community (-1) user, so they are derived from the votes, yes...but we don't actually move a table record over to the destination database, they're still on the original on a now-deleted post.  I have no idea if that was a clear description, sorry!

Comment: Maybe 1% reputation bonus :D ?

Comment: I think the question we all want to know is... how has this affected the Skeetmeister?

Comment: Why this question showing up in my homepage? no its showing up in every page I navigate .. :/

Comment: @NickCraver: is this ethical? You put the *originals* in hibernation while the *copies* live on their lives in their new place! Oh, what is this world coming to? :-)

Comment: well, At SO, I got additional 1 point. Gee, I thought I'll lose some points.

Comment: after all this time?

Comment: I came looking for evidence of the heaven and earth movement, only to find out it was just a bunch of computer bits moved around to improve one's ability to puff up one's chest in the privacy of one's own home (or work, or car, or...) over how to better move other computer bits around. Somehow a bit anticlimactic, but I'm glad it is being done just the same :-).

Comment: I've been on this site for over 3 years now and this is the second time 500-1000 points have been slashed off my reputation.  Needless to say I'm un-impressed and not happy.

Comment: Could you please make this a "closeable" prompt with the little X? please?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a community wiki?

Comment: @Emil more like 'not a real question' lol

Comment: chat is still showing the old values.

Comment: Did you keep any record or statistics of how much scores changed when this was applied?  I'd be curious.  Mine barely changed, but I was careful to keep it in sync with reputation page, despite the painfulness of doing so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - we record the old and new reputation on *every* recalc, not easy to query but we have the data, yes.

Comment: Noooooooo. You should have granted amnesty for all past fake reputation.

Comment: Now I feel weird, as I'm apparently the only person here who has no idea what zir rep is.

Comment: Ugh.. Not a good start to the day!

Comment: For anyone who was wondering, Jon Skeet lost only 13 points this time because he regularly recalculates his rep.

Comment: Now where is my reputation gone all of a sudden :(

Comment: I lost 20%.  How that happen?

Comment: @demongolem You have edited a number of posts that were deleted afterwards. So you lost the +2 rep bonus you got for editing that post. But that looks only like 5% of your total rep or so.

Comment: It would only be fair to lose our deleted reputation if and only if our deleted downvotes get removed as well. Is that taking place? If not, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @CodeInChaos That's right.  I look in my activity and see the like -2, -4, and so on for deletes, but I lost far more than I can see under the reputation tab.  It is as if positive reputation was taken away from me as well.

Comment: I think that if you are going to give users the ability to down vote a question then you should force them to comment on why they choose to down vote an answer. I don't really understand the down voting option anyway, I think it prevents people from posting questions or answers that may help other posters which I think is the real reason for this site the exchange of thoughts and ideas, correct?

Comment: If reputation is always correct then why showing a big alert message like this ......Reputation changed unexpectedly? Don't know where to turn? We've moved heaven and earth to ensure your score is always correct!

Comment: @zod - It *wasn't* always correct, it is now...which necessitated a global recalc to get in line, which had a large reputation impact for some people.

Comment: @Nick  i lost hundreds of points 2  months back . I had some fight with moderators on some questions . Any plans to give back the points. ?? do you have anyway to find who all are lost their points and how much. can you give me 500+ leap day special :-)

Comment: It actualy doesnt matter for me.I'm screwed anyway :)

Comment: Why do I always seem to lose rep when these recalcs happen?  Why can't I ever GAIN rep?

Comment: @BoltBait It's possible to gain rep if none of your posts have been deleted, and you've downvoted a lot of posts which have subsequently been deleted. That's how the old system works, at least

Comment: Can I take rep. bribes?

Comment: If you take money out of an ATM and the money is fake is it 'proper' that you can still spend the money?...

Comment: Provided that a clerk is blind, then yes.

Comment: @Mureinik it's not bad to do minor edits to fix stuff, but at least do it properly. For example here, it wasn't only changing http:// to https://. the blog domain itself changed. In other cases, when we (users with full edit privilege) perform minor edit, we should also fix other things in the post. Please, put bit more effort when editing, or don't edit at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 234):

All sounds nice, but you're still missing a point that I think should be addressed. Currently, when things get deleted, they just disappear from your history. That's not very helpful, especially concerning reputation. When my reputation randomly drops by 40, it would be nice to be able to **see** that in my history. Would it be possible to make this change show up in the history?

I think it should show as a negative amount applied with a simple 'deleted" message. It would be nice to list the title of the question, and those with 10k rep would still be able to view it. At least knowing the title, we know *what* post got deleted. Reputation lost for deleted posts should only affect the daily reputation cap if those posts were from the same day cycle (just a side note).

[image: Example]

Of course this would also have the inverse effect for a post which was deleted that had downvotes and you actually *gained* reputation, showing a positive amount, with the same restrictions for the daily reputation cap.

---

**Update:** Here's a little preview of some of the things you can now find:

[image]

Comment: That's part of this change, when a post is deleted you'll see that in your reputation history tab.

Comment: @NickCraver: that's nice! You should include it in your question!

Comment: @Nick: Awesome! :) You stated `The reputation history in your profile will be more detailed and accurate` but I wanted to make sure this was included.

Comment: @Martin - that was point #4, but added this as a specific example so it's much clearer :)

Comment: @NickCraver This doesn't align 100% with what you're doing, but... this *almost* lets users find any of their own deleted posts: as long as the post has been voted on its deletion will cause a rep change so it'll show up here. I'd be thrilled if this could also show when unvoted posts are deleted, providing the complete record of a user's deleted posts to them. (Maybe you already meant to do this, but I didn't want to risk not suggesting it.)

Comment: @JeremyBanksʬʬʬ - It will show when they're deleted, how much the rep delta was, and the title, but we won't link to them unless you're a moderator...it's just to give you an idea where the reputation was.  We *never* link to lists of deleted content, it introduces a ton of trouble, and I can't see changing that behavior here.  The title showing is flame bait enough for meta questions, I'm hoping even leaving that in won't be an issue.

Comment: @Nick: Really? I'm pretty sure my flagging history is a list, and it links to deleted content. :o

Comment: @animuson - that's linking to *other* deleted content (not some you owned 99% of the time), but I'd consider that a bug none the less, will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @NickCraver I really think deleted posts should be linked (both rep and flagging history). If I want to review that deleted content, all you're doing is adding the necessity for me to plug the title into the search field (or browser history) and scroll down. For questions, I can kind of understand it, but they should be available to 10k users because *we've earned it*. Otherwise, I could just start favoriting every single one of my questions to keep track of them.

Comment: also, [/tools?tab=delete](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete), a list of deleted content that goes back up to 30 days.

Comment: Without a link the flagging history/reputation history entries will be mostly useless. I will usually not remember what I answered to a question with a certain title a year ago. Or what I flagged on a question with a certain title. If you remove the link you can also just remove the question title, since without a link it's useless.

Comment: Something to note on your update, if you're a 10k user those post titles *are* linked.

Comment: 49 downvotes? Damn doesn't somebody hate you.

Comment: @badp: It was [a joke](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/879470#879470) really.

Comment: I lost about 200 rep by recalculation, and I see nothing.

Comment: @userunknown: You won't see it listed directly under *today*. It will be listed under whichever day the deletion, unupvote, or whatever it was *actually occurred*. You may have to search a little bit to find the places where you actually lost reputation. The key feature update here is that all deletions, etc that occur *from now on* will be instantly updated and visible in your history. The global recalc was just to update all the users and get them to the same place.

Comment: So how should I find them between other, negative reputation changes? Ok - found some "unaccepted -15" and "deleted -30". But too much work and guessing, to find the justification for the loss.

Comment: @lunboks, I don't think search works for deleted content. It has also been removed from Google's spider index via `robots.txt` or similar.

Answer (score 55):

[image: Fix all teh reputations!]

I know we're kind of in the later stages of this, but can we update how tag wiki reputation is displayed in the reputation history? Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Reputation history]

This is, obviously, not very specific. You have to click through to see what tag wiki (or excerpt) it's talking about. Can we get the tag wiki's title and the "excerpt" keyword (for those it applies too) added to these lines as well, like how it's displayed in your suggestions activity:

[image: Suggestions activity]

Also, it displays in the preview, why not the tab?

[image: Reputation preview]

Comment: This seems off-topic -- but a good idea, have you posted a [tag:feature-request] for it?)

Comment: I'll take a look at this today if time allows, as long as we can fetch the data in a reasonable way, that sounds like a fine suggestion (before we *couldn't* fetch it in a reasonable way).

Comment: I know you were probably writing/drawing with a mouse above, but I can't help but feel that you should have had a "FIX ALL THE REPUTATIONS" headline at the top :)

Comment: @edoloughlin: Like so?

Comment: @animuson Nice!

Answer (score 53):

I, personally, think it's completely irrational to ***LOSE*** reputation points just because a question you answered was deleted!

If the *answer* was deleted, or if a question *you asked* was deleted, then it makes sense.

However, if I answer a question, and it gets any votes (1 or 100 - doesn't matter), and then the question gets deleted, you're basically saying that all the effort that went into answering it was for naught. And if *THAT* is the case, then why bother answering?

Note - I'm not in this for the reputation, but it's a nice side-bonus, and randomly removing heretofore established bonuses is mean-spirited, at the least.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure you should lose rep if the SO gods later decide a question you answered should be deleted.

Comment: Of course you should. The question was deleted for a *reason*. Why should you get reputation for answering a question that's **not a good fit for Stack Overflow**? I think this encourages users to actually **analyze** the question for its value and rather than submitting an answer, vote to close it (or flag it) if it doesn't belong here.

Comment: It's even more annoying to lose a gold medal from an answer that was turned to wiki **after** you got the medal :((

Comment: I am not so much bothered by the reputation loss (since I have little to start with), but the content loss is lamentable and I would really like to see some of those deleted good answers.

Comment: What if I answer a question, it gets a lot of upvotes, gets accepted as the answer, then two years later the OP deletes it because he thinks it makes him look stupid?  That's not being removed due to poor fit with the site, and I lose a bunch of reputation. (Which I just did)

Comment: @Stephen: Question owners [can't delete if there are any upvoted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471).

Comment: @animuson - you're missing the point, I think: there are several questions that **MONTHS** or **YEARS** later have been deleted because they're *no longer* viewed as "a good fit". Retroactively applying today's rules to yesterday's content is at the very least rude!

Comment: I agree.  There ought to be a statue of limitations on this.  It's absurd that months or even *years* after you've answered a question, you can have the rep subtracted because after that much time, someone's decided the question wasn't a good fit.

Comment: @Kyralessa - now if only the SE gods would grace us with their response :)

Comment: And yet another issue on this - if a user is deleted, you lose rep associated from their question\answer\votes :|

Comment: @warren, Doesn't the user's questions stay even after he has been deleted? I've seen many questions asked by "unlinked profile".

Comment: @Pacerier - so far as I know, yes

Comment: @warren, Hmm, then why does your previous comment state that rep would be lost?

Comment: @Pacerier - it's difference from how it used to be to now

Comment: I meant _statute_ of limitations, of course.

Answer (score 43):

One minor issue I found. The descriptions (titles) for unupvote/undownvote events are inconsistent.

> *answer was unupvoted*
>   vs.
>   *dwonvote  was removed from a post*

In my opinion, "unupvoted" sounds a bit awkward as a verb, so you might want to sync that up. Also, the typo in "downvote" isn't mine.

Comment: @lunboks Correct the dwonvote!

Comment: I find the awkwardness of "unupvoted" and "undownvoted" to be rather charming.

Comment: @downvoter Listen to what jmendeth just said.

Comment: @NickCraver I don't want to post another nit-pick answer, but currently, it's "upvote was removed from a answer". I believe it should be "*an* answer".

Comment: @lunboks - thanks, will be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 20):

Congratulations on the new system. Abolishing recalcs is a big and important step, and the new reputation tracker, showing all past changes, is awesome for accountability. I feel that this was quite a substantial improvement in terms of felt usability, even though it doesn’t actually affect the handling of the site at all.

**EDIT** And this feature is just awesome:

[image]

Comment: Additionally I wish there was a timer before a downvote or upvote was possible (as in did you read the question so you can vote?). Downvoting based on appearances can throw a question into obscurity, and it happens way too often.

Answer (score 11):

What happened to the SO league ranking that was display in the profile's rep summary, does it also need a recalc or something? this was one of my favorite things to watch:

Old:
[image: Old rep summary]

New:
[image: New rep summary]

On the plus side I only lost 15 rep cause of the recalc :D

---

Also, it would be nice to have upvotes that have are partially(or fully) lost rep due to the rep cap displaying something to that effect (I assume this is the magical +2 rep?):
[image]

Comment: I didn't notice the league ranking disappearing! As for the reputation cap thing, it's always been like that and I don't see why that should change. Everyone who's read the FAQ knows there's a 200 reputation daily cap, and any logical person can figure out why an upvote would show as +2 instead of +10 when they've gained 260 reputation for the day. What's to be so confused about?

Comment: @animuson: seeing as everything else was being demystified, it seemed natural to have this added.

Comment: As for the league percentages, it looks like those are still being updated. They appear here on meta and on other sites, so I'd expect to see them showing back up at some point.

Comment: The leagues need a massive backfill, which we've written code for but couldn't run last night due to us pushing our database servers to their limits running recalcs as fast as possible.  The reputation leagues will be fixed today.

Comment: @NickCraver: Great to know it hasn't disappeared :)

Comment: The rep tables have been backfilled and the links have returned :)

Comment: @NickCraver: awesome! now I can gloat over my league standings in percentages again :D

Answer (score 9):

Do I need to change my mental model of how the rep cap works?

**The behavior I'm used to:** Suppose that on Monday I get 20 upvotes on question A, and then one upvote on question B. The upvote on question B is eaten by the cap. Further suppose that on Tuesday one of the upvoters on A retract their upvote. My rep total immediately decreases by 10, but I can regain it by triggering a recalc, because now the upvote on B can fit in under Monday's rep cap.

**Is this still the case?** The annoncement seems to say that the retraction of the upvote on A now counts as a separate reputation delta *occurring on Tuesday*, so my rep movements would be

```
Monday: 21 upvotes ~ 210 points, capped to 200
Tuesday: 1 unupvote
```

thus the net effect would be that I've gained 190 rep, in contrast to 200 rep in the old system.

Or am I misunderstanding either the old or the new system?

Comment: The old behavior remains here, you'd still get 200 rep on that day.  think of it as when an upvote (that counted) from a capped day is reversed, you were instantly recacled...you'd get that 10 rep from another vote that was 0 previously because you were over the cap back then.

Comment: @NickCraver: Okay, so in the reputation tab I would see +200 on Monday and a -0 entry on Tuesday for the unupvote? Or I'll only see the unupvote at all when it affects my total rep?

Comment: Honestly I've been looking at tens of thousands of numbers all day and the brain is fried...the 0 entry *sounds* right but I'll have to double check, will get to it maybe over the weekend.

Comment: No sweat. I'll just see if I can get somebody on chat to conspire to upvote-and-retract the next time it seems like I'll cap.

Comment: It turns out that such unupvotes get listed with no number next to them, like capped upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

**Fix how deletions/reversals appear in history:**

This has really confused some users, making it look like they've lost reputation for the day or that they are unable to "reach the rep cap" for the day. This is most thoroughly [outlined by Greg Hewgill](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124325/141525).

The problem is when content gets deleted or voting fraud gets reversed, it shows up for the day that occurs. This makes sense, because it allows users to quickly figure out why they lost reputation. However, it also confuses some users because the daily total is skewed by that event.

[image: Original reputation history]

Here, I lost 76 reputation because of voting fraud the previous day. I also received an upvote for an answer, which I later deleted for a net effect of 0 there, then got an upvote on a question and a downvote on another answer. My net gain for the day is actually +3, but it looks horrible because of that -76 which affects the +76 from the previous day.

A good fix would be to separate these reversal events into two separate counts. Whenever a deletion or reversal takes place on your account that affects reputation from a previous day, it should display as a separate number next to the number representing your gain (or loss) for the current day. Something like this:

[image: Fixed reputation history]

This would tell me that I've gained 3 reputation today, cool! It also tells me that I've lost 76 reputation from something, so I should probably look at it. Expanding would tell me that voting fraud was reversed which cost me 76 reputation, also cool! This should also be the case if you gained reputation (possible from serial downvotes). For example, if I had lost 76 reputation the previous day and that day has reversed those to gain me the 76 reputation back, it should display as `+3 / +76` to show me that I'm sitting at +3 for *today* and I gained 76 from something else on a previous day.

Comment: I had to read your explanation to understand why the +3 did not match the total upvotes, and likewise why the -76 did not match all downvotes. I guess, to me, this means that such vote split is not very intuitive (especially given other places where such splits *do* split upvotes and downvotes).

Comment: @Arjan: It's basically separating the values on the point of (what's happened **today** / things that affect **other days**).

Comment: I understand your explanation, but *seeing* it made me think you were reporting some bug. So, I kind of expect people to be confused by such vote split too. Of course, there could be a different rendering if people want such split.

Comment: @Arjan: Perhaps there could be an additional separator between the votes that count for today's count and the events that count for the second value? That way the two sections are somewhat separated when the day is expanded.

Comment: Word is that there are a number of changes coming shortly. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to have been no distinction made between deletes and migrations. Migrated questions have been marked as deleted in the reputation tab, which is a little confusing...

Is it possible to distinguish between them? Or are [migrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815796/ora-01654-unable-to-extend-index-name-of-the-index-by-128-in-tablespace-name?noredirect=1) [questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10514/ora-01654-unable-to-extend-index-name-of-the-index-by-128-in-tablespace-name/10516#10516) just marked as deleted?

Comment: Migrated answers on the source site *are* deleted, there's no plan to distinguish them at this time, that may change later.

Comment: That explains that then, thanks @NickCraver... I know it's petty but my inner data wonk wants to distinguish between the two if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry, but this makes me very angry.

Here is my issue:
I worked really hard to build up my SO reputation.  Like many things on SO, what you do on day x can be altered many days into the future, in ways that you cannot anticipate or expect.

For my account, my reputation suddenly went down by hundreds of points.  Checking the "log", it appears to be for items where were deleted.  But the deleted items were valid questions when I asked them.

Most troubling about this is that SO users are encouraged to display their reputation on others sites, and I do this with my blog.  To have a sudden downgrade in my reputation, which is part of my blog public profile, is equivalent to slander and defamation, in my opinion [just imagine if you put your credit score on your website, and suddenly the credit agency changed the formula and downgraded you].

I've been suspicious of SO for awhile because of these changes, and my current thinking is that it is time to say goodbye.  I've been a member since 2007 or early 2008 [I don't remember off hand], and it will be sad to leave...but the actions of the site are the problem, not anything that I have done as an active member of the SO community.

Does anyone else share this sentiment?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** My reputation was reduced by 380 points, the vast amount being for old questions which were deleted.  These old questions were perfectly fine when first asked, but as SO (evolved/devolved), they were no longer valid and were closed...sometimes YEARS after they were opened.  And now deleted.  That's amazin[ly bad].

Comment: I don't think you were a member in 2007.

Comment: It's not really new. You could have been 'recalculated' and lost those points too, maybe after being the victim of some serial downvoting. The plus here is that you will now have less (and smaller) sudden surprises.

Comment: @Henk: my start date was an estimate, as I indicated.  My reputation was displayed publicly on multiple websites for years [apparently artifically inflated]...what is worse: to artifically inflate, or to suddenly downgrade people like me?  [either way, not anything which I did through my use of SO].

Comment: This isn't the first global rep recalc in history, there have been several -- there was one [less than a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010). So it's not like being a member forever means you took more of a hit; it's still only going to apply to stuff that happened since the last recalc. And it looks like you didn't even notice the others, so ragequitting now that they've finally fixed this behavior and it will never happen again seems kind of insane. Particularly over 380 rep, which you can literally recover in two days

Comment: Um, honestly, I don't consider gathering 3,648 rep points over the course of *three years and five months* to be "working hard."  Now, if you were Jon Skeet and your rep got halved, I'd say you had a point...

Comment: Just realized I linked to the recalc that happened two years ago; [here's the one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-reputation-drop-problem-points-disappeared-and-score-lost-recalc) that was last year

Comment: `Joined Oct 1 '08, last seen 1 hour ago`

Comment: You’ve lost ~1% of your reputation. No big deal, right?

Comment: @Konrad - I wouldn't be commenting over 1%

Comment: @Al - Something isn't right with my start date.  I took a new job in June 2008, and on the job before that I know I was a member of SO and had posted questions.  I think my start date has been altered by SO at some point.

Comment: @pearcewg Sorry, I can’t count. But while I can empathise with your pain (the first rep recalc in history hit me even more (*much* more) severely!) remember that this change doesn’t actually come out of the blue. The new reputation is actually the *real*, legitimate score. The displayed score before was never the right one, it was merely out of sync with reality.

Comment: @pearcewg The same can actually happen with your account balance in online banking. Still the bank will never pay you the difference between the displayed and the real amount even though this error can actually put you at a financial disadvantage. This has already happened to me (overdrafted my account due to wrong balance displayed in online banking and had to pay fees; the bank acknowledged the problem and even that it was their fault but told me it’s a technical limitation and to suck it up).

Comment: I lost more than 200 point 2 months before  when i had a fight with SO  I talk bad about moderators :-) and one fine day  i lost hundreds of point

Comment: This is THE MOST HYPERBOLIC ARGUMENT IN THE HISTORY OF THE WORLD.  `equivalent to slander and defamation` is pretty over the top.  It's a bunch of fake points that don't mean anything and can't be used for anything, and are FREE TO GIVE.  Huh?

Comment: Here is why my argument is valid: http://imgur.com/VrCN8  The vast majority of my downgrade in reputation is because the questions I commented on were deleted!  That wasn't anything I did, but I'm being penalized for it.  Bye bye SO.

Comment: Bye bye pearcewg

Comment: @pearcewg you aren't being penalized.  It's a correction.  You didn't LOSE anything, something was removed that should never have been granted in the first place.  It sucks that you got so much rep from off-topic questions in the first place, but if that's your only contribution then don't let the screen door hit you on the way out.

Answer (score 4):

Showing rep-changed due to removed up/down-votes and accepted answers could generate confusing noise:

A couple of days/weeks ago a colleague of mine (~10 rep) who apparently didn't quite understand votes or the general idea of SO, was repeatedly clicking the accept-answer button of an answer to his question (or up-vote, I don't recall which) in pure confusion. I tried to explain to him what this meant and what he was causing with this random clicking (I'm not sure if I managed to communicate the idea to him in the end).

Anyway, if all these actions would have been shown to the user who posted the answer, that could have caused even more confusion, but certainly some unwanted noise. Maybe this should be given some thought when implementing the new system (perhaps a one-minute undo-block, or something).

Comment: All of these events would be collapsed into a single title in the default view, which could then be expanded to see the separate events (all the accepts and unaccepts). This is a very edge case, so it's not really something they're worried about. [See this related topic.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123696/merge-together-all-actions-of-a-single-user-on-a-question)

Comment: I think your colleague may have been confused about how clicks work in general.

Comment: @MatthewRead: As far as I could tell it was a combination of not understanding the concept of reputation and the behaviour of the interface. If you catch users off-guard they will forget how to apply the most basic stuff.

Comment: It seems like an edge case, but I was a bit surprised to see exactly this on my recent activity rep page today. A user accepted, unaccepted, and accepted the answer, within seconds. On the one hand, if that's what they did, showing it isn't wrong. On the other hand, we add hysteresis to systems sometimes for a reason. :-)

Comment: Actually, twice just today: http://i.imgur.com/o6TkV.png I suspect this accept/unaccept/accept is more common than we thought (presumably folks with direct access to the data can readily check).

Comment: It would appear that this accept/unaccept/accept and upvote/un-upvote/upvote thing really is very common; I've [done a feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124876/the-new-rep-handling-needs-some-noise-cancelling-hysteresis) to mute it a bit.

Answer (score 4):

That *'Image thumbnail view/editor in JFrame'* should show a 'correct' marking like threads *'How to use ProgressMonitor..'* and *'Is there any way..'*, shouldn't it?  Is that part of the new changes?  Is it intended?

[image: Rep. image]

[Also: (grumbles) lost 176 rep. in these maneuverings.  But that is just a comment, it seems it was part of the general re-calc.]

Comment: hmmm [for example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114431/164879)

Comment: Yup, this was a bug, thanks!  A fix is in the next build and will roll out today.

Comment: @Nick Craver please can you check my twice -15 (answer accepted) [userProfile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/714968/mkorbel?tab=reputation) and with [first from 01/march/2012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9500088/714968) and [second from 29/february/2012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9495850/714968), errrhgt what's really happens with accepted answers,

Comment: @NickCraver  Some things I especially like about SE sites. 1) Feed-back. 2) The proactive attitude of the folks who create and maintain them.  :)

Answer (score 4):

How does **unaccept** and **accept** works?

[image]

why they differs?

Comment: Same with me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124207/180153

Comment: See also the later [What do the reputation values for unaccept and accept mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124202/what-do-the-reputation-values-for-unaccept-and-accept-mean) by the same author.

Comment: These are multiple events that were rolled up (the *latest* date is used for any rollup in the time view).  But we can be a bit clearer here, I've added a tooltip in the next build that'll say "question was accepted 2 times" for example.  In the post view you can expand to see each of these individual events.

Comment: One interesting side effect I'm noticing (on SO specifically) is that there is a lot more volatility in the answers accepted, unaccepted, reaccepted, reunaccepted, and even rereaccepted - and that's just one answer for one question on one day (today).  Ignorance was blissful.  No harm done - it is interesting, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

I woke up to find that I'd taken a 3K+ hit.  It's pretty shocking.

Comment: One thing this change accomplishes is that 3k hit will never happen again, instead your reputation will be kept in sync so you have no large surprises like this.

Comment: This is the second time it's happened to me.  I lost another 1K or so a year back.  I suppose I'll just have to suck it up again.

Answer (score 4):

As for me, there's another issue behind these changes that is worth discussing.

As the FAQ says, reputation is a rough measurement of **how much the community trusts you**. That said, every person could go to a user's profile page and easily locate all his 'bad' questions or answers, because all of them were marked with catchy red color. That way, the reputation log served as a simple display of how often does this user make notable mistakes.

Of course, *errare humanum est*. But now, the profile page of an average user can get overwhelmed with red marks that immediately attract negative reaction. But the thing is, the user often has nothing to do with the fact that OP had changed his mind or pressed the wrong button.
It has also become difficult to locate downvotes among all this new stuff.

I have been a member of StackOverflow only for a week, but I was kinda proud that my reputation log was almost completely 'green'. Until now.

What I'm trying to say is, maybe it's better to leave the detailed explanation of the reputation only for the user himself? Or at least provide some filters on the profile page that would allow to hide certain items if the person is not interested in them.

As an alternative solution, maybe there should be another color for 'unaccept'/'undownvote'/'unupvote' actions.

Comment: Why would it matter what color it is? If it was purple, would that be better? How about orange? Or pink?

Comment: @CodyGray: it would matter because it would separate failures from adjustments. A heavily downvoted question/answer is the user's fault (and should be red), but, for example, a "-30" for an answer to a deleted question is a system adjustment, and the user has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

I can report a little sync problem. My rep on SO is currently reporting as 1 fewer than the true value. This has been so for an hour or so. I'm at the rep cap for the day and some post-cap downvoting followed by upvotes to return me to the cap level appear to have resulted in the discrepancy. Perhaps you had not intended that this behaviour (quite familiar of old) would be changed, but that 's how I read your post.

Anyway, as one SW dev to another, I thought I'd give you what may be a bug report.

Comment: Thanks David, there is indeed a very old problem here, but not one with an immediate fix...this is a core path used all over the place, so we need to analyze a bit before deploying a fix.

Comment: I guess that means you need to leave the manual recalc code in place at least until you can tackle this.

Comment: @Nick Ooh, the skew just fixed itself. Perhaps you've really got on top of this!

Answer (score 4):

This might be unrelated to the recent changes, but in case it is:

If a question is deleted by a moderator, a bounty is refunded. (And it might also refund [the automatic downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84978/should-questions-closed-as-not-a-real-question-and-off-topic-get-an-automati) that occurs on closing?) Is that the expected/intended behavior?

And would the same apply when deleting one's own question? If so, then in theory, this might allow for: open a bounty on a bad question, still don't get any answers or get one answer but [don't upvote that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471), delete the question, have the bounty refunded.

Background:

Yesterday I asked for deletion/migration of [an off-topic October 2009 question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537469/google-is-changing-its-referrer-urls-from-search-into-url-any-known-issues). It happened to have an old bounty (which was never awarded). And that bounty was refunded. Robert, who deleted it, confirmed he did not refund anything manually.

[image]

(I guess the +39 implies 50 bounty, 3 upvotes and 2 downvotes were reverted: 50 − 15 + 4. Google cache shows 2 net upvotes two weeks ago. So I guess Google cache actually shows +3/−1 and hence the 19:22 automatic downvote was the 2nd downvote, and was reverted too.)

Answer (score 3):

Can we do/trigger recalculation by our own at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation (don't want to wait till automatic trigger or want automatic trigger but want to see how much reputation will be mine after recalc).

We can see there day by day votes,rep today, rep this week, rep this month, rep this quarter, rep this year,rep from bonuses, reputation from suggested edits. See below image.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand...are you asking something, or reporting a bug?   Soon the recalc on that page will no longer be necessary, and will likely be removed (as it will have zero affect on anything...since you're always being kept in sync after these changes).

Comment: My query/ statement is that we can trigger recalculation by our own. But query is that button always there (every day)? Or it is kept only in this period(whenever recalculation is being done.)

Comment: Oh, that's been there for some time...that hasn't changed in recent history, but it will be going away, since the need for it to exist (reputation skew) is also going away.

Comment: Is there any problem if user trigger reputation recalc by own?

Comment: @NickCraver: I'd keep it for at least a couple of months, while the system shakes out, if only to give people a way to prove to themselves that it really works (you know what people are like).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - oh we won't eliminate anything until we're sure it's rock solid, we'll be monitoring for any skews over actual for the next week at least.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the new system is working properly on stackoverflow.

> Your reputation will be correct at all times
>
> ...
>
> This means your reputation will go up and down more than it has
>   previously, but it will be in sync. To think of it more easily:
>   imagine that a recalc will be done after every action in the system.

I take this to mean there can be no skew anymore.  But I have `** total rep 8025 :)` on the recalc page, and 8040 on the homepage (I tried a shift-refresh too).  Anyway, just thought you might like to check it out.

[image]

Comment: Recently the rep calc changes have made the /reputation page and recalcs obsolete. My guess is that you got some added back for deleted posts which used to be removed, see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) in the paragraph that starts with `First` about halfway down.

Comment: thanks, you are probably right because i had some deleted post in the first question showing there in the supercollider

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, other than the benefit of everything being consistent in the back end - it seems a bit pointless to me. Thinking about the impact on the community, does it really matter that rep is reclaimed in such a manner?

For many people who have passed a landmark, or are approaching a landmark - you'll get an initial reaction of "why has my rep been stolen?" (sample size: 1 :)) - hey, I'm over it but its not a warm and fuzzy feeling inside.

Comment: At some point in time, the same would have happened if [for some other reason](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) a global reputation recalc would be required. At that point, folks might lose even more reputation. And people did not complain when [voting on questions became free](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free).

Comment: The benefit is being consistent *in the front end*. I agree that losing huge chunks of reputation sucks – but this already happened before, at every single rep recalc. From now on, it will never happen again (assuming there will be no change in the reputation algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to get my rep skewed again. Hooray!

Apparently the new system and the ghetto [`/reputation` report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) disagree on how much rep I should have.

Today I hit the cap, took a 60 rep loss, and the new system put me at **3484** reputation.

/reputation said I should have **3499**. So I recalced and apparently, this is now how much I have. I just received another question upvote that was lost to the cap, but still, /reputation now tells me I should have **3504**.

Comment: Thanks, we'll take a look....we're seeing very, *very* rare skew cases now, we're tracking down where they're slipping through.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at my accounts tab here on this site:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144983/boltbait?tab=accounts

I have a SO rep of 7181.

If I go over to SO, my rep is 6584.

I thought this was going to fix the rep to be updated everywhere instantly.

Guess not.

Anyway, I just lost 10% of my rep because some of the questions I answered got deleted.  That doesn't seem right.  I still answered the questions.  People still liked the answers I gave.  I'm assuming someone got some value out of them.  But I lose out the benefit because someone comes along later and deletes the question? Bah!

The same thing happened the last time you guys did a global recalc.  I lost ~10% of my rep then too.  Do you ever consider how that will affect your users before you do something like that?  This was one of the major reasons I don't come here and answer questions anymore.  I figured, "what's the point?  I'll just lose the rep later anyway."

Comment: The skew is due to the network aggregation needing a backfill, which will happen tomorrow. "Do you ever consider how that will affect your users before you do something like that?"  yes, which is the entire reason for this change, reputation will now be in sync at all times, rather than global recalcs coming as a shock and a major rep change.

Comment: @Nick Craver - my rep on SO today is 7696! But it doesn't show up here as that. Seriously, WTF? I think this system is broken.

Comment: We managed to break the aggregator again last night by recalcing 1.6 million users in a few hours...it's ***really*** not designed with this use case in mind.  That being said, we hope to never do it again.

Comment: Have you considered hiring a Validation Team? Or, at least doing code reviews? ;)

Comment: 24 hours later and my rep is still not showing the same number on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

Given the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes#comment328892_123330) to another answer, there is a bug on the displaying of a link to a deleted question when it is upvoted. See the upvote on `Jun 27 '11` to [Games which can be helpful as a minor distraction](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25361/games-which-can-be-helpful-as-a-minor-distraction/25362#25362) in my [reputation history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7127/mark-hurd?tab=reputation).

Comment: FYI I can see the same issue here on meta.

Comment: The links are only visible for 10k users, that's intentional behavior at the moment (and consistent with other places in the UI).

Comment: @NickCraver I'm only 928 here and 212 on Gaming, and the link is still there (on Gaming at least) when I'm logged out.

Comment: @NickCraver NB I _am_ referring to earlier _upvotes_ not when the question is deleted.

Comment: I assume this _is_ now a known bug, but I'll just confirm it also happens for downvoted questions that are later deleted. That is the link to the question is still present for the downvote, although not for the deletion.

Comment: In my comment above I meant "answer" not "question"!

Answer (score 0):

It's not just deleted content whose points were lost!  If you had upvotes on a question/answer that was later moved to a different Stack Exchange website...

...poof, the double-counted points are gone.

Arghh!

Comment: Yes, of course. They've always been gone, ever since the post was moved. Your displayed reputation score just hadn't been updated. Fortunately, that problem is solved for good now.

Comment: Yup, this is by-design, because the content on the source site *was deleted*, immediately if not eventually (answers are immediate, questions later)...*but* you'll now get that reputation on the destination site within 5 minutes, rather than requiting a recalc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't unterstand why I have lost rep. Yesterday I had 1886 now 1825. Well I read that rep is decrised if I delete an answer. What's about an updated question where you see that your answer was horridly wrong, but not downvoted. Is that a reason to loose rep?

Well the Update is funny I can see that a guy accepted and unaccepted an answer two times^^

Comment: Same here. The OP talks about rep being a few hours off d/t delayed recalc from deleted posts, but unless a huge amount of posts have been deleted in the last days, I don't see why my rep would go down?

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz - this being in sync is *just now the case*, before your reputation was indefinitely out of sync until a recalc was performed (which we ran for everyone last night).  This change is to keep your reputation in sync at all times, rather than these extreme changes due to an approximately yearly global recalc.

Comment: @NickCraver: ah, "approximately yearly recalc" was the missing piece of info - thanks!

Comment: Yesterday I had over 14K, today I have 13K. So mine went down over 1000. SO basically, some day that was going to happen, they've just hastened the inevitable.  I had lots of questions that got deleted because Stack Overflow changed over the years and turned into a "No Bikeshed" zone. As a fan of bikeshed questions, I get hit by this hard.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am not sure if this is known. But, on other sites, english.stackexchange.com in this example, the reputation shown is the old value (on the profile page). So, the old value was 1563(shown on english.stackexchange.com for stackoverflow)  and now it is 1471 (shown on stackoverflow).

Comment: This will be fixed in a backfill this weekend...it was such a massive change of scores for well over a million users that the normal mechanisms for keeping the accounts data in sync just can't handle it.  The backfill was planned anyway to recover from a hiccup a week ago, so we felt it was fine for this to be out of line for about a day until that happens.

Answer (score 0):

On my answer of this question : [How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9513489/372239) , I've got a score of 5 points. How is this possible, according to reputation tab, it should be 65 points?

```
10   today
+10  1 hour ago upvote  How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command
145  yesterday
+15  20:36  accept  PHP Phone Number Replace Regex
+10  17:27  upvote  Javascript string regex /.*/gm does not catch all line at once
+20  16:45  upvote  If statement in javascript regex
+10  15:26  upvote  How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command
+20  15:20  upvote  Javascript string regex /.*/gm does not catch all line at once
+15  15:06  accept  How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command
-15  15:06  unaccept    How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command
+10  14:24  upvote  function declaration to function pointer declaration using perl
+15  13:59  accept  Euro symbol in PHP ereg_replace
+10  13:36  upvote  How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command
+15  13:36  accept  How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command
+20  11:30  upvote  How to read query parameter value from URL using perl command
```

Comment: You have 5 upvotes (+50) and an accept (+15), so the +65 you see is correct...is there something obvious I'm missing?  Honest question, I just woke up :)

Comment: @NickCraver: Sorry, I've made a confusion between upvote and reputation points. That just because I've got 60 points less than  yesterday evening and I don't know why. The similarity of these 60 points confused me. Nevertheless why these 60 points have disapeared?

Comment: those points were from deleted posts, the whole problem in the question of "reputation skew" is that when a post was deleted it *never* took effect until a recalc (which was performed for everyone last night).  Now that deletion change will happen within 5 minutes and you'll see it in your profile's reputation tab so you know exactly what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Probably asking really dumb right here will get rather get me another rep dip, but I still don't understand what happened. My rep dropped by ~70 over night. I have not been active very recently, but I realized it was headed south when I just checked droidstack which I rarely do. 
Because of a slow 3G network I just saw my old rep and then saw it diminished.

I checked my profile and found no downvotes, unacc. or whatsoever. Plus I checked the network profile graph time line (please bring that one back to SO) and SO wasn't there. I only found programmers and statistical analysis.

So the question is: Do I just have to be a little patient to get my rep back? Or should I mentally prepare for never getting it back because what I see now is my true rep?

Comment: The latter is the case, what you see now is your true rep, it will constantly be in sync from now on.

Comment: I’m surprised you even noticed a 70 point dip at your reputation level. But SO [*has* a reputation graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366256/ran2?tab=reputation&sort=graph). Better yet, the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366256/ran2?tab=reputation&sort=time) display shows you exactly where you lost the 70 reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Well something is wrong with the new calculations I *think*. Possibly related to unawarded bounty points. If you open a bounty on a question and do not accept an answer you lose the the bounty points. I think after the new calculations you not only lose all the points but also lose another half of the bounty that is awarded to the first answered question (or the one with the most upvotes or whatever the rule is).

Comment: If you do not award a bounty, [the bounty is lost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124250/wheres-my-bounty-points-gone).

Comment: Yeah sorry I mean you lose the bounty plus you lose another half of the bounty.

Comment: I assume [you mean this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465120/wcf-4-0-rest-username-password-authentication). You set out a Bounty of 250, you did not award it, so it was awarded by the system (You lose 250, the awarded user gets 125). See the [Bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for further information.

Comment: Do you have an example you can point me to?